# How to separate two adsense accounts

Tags: google-adsense

When trying to open my Google Adsense account (attached to my.email@gmail.com), I got a message saying:

> Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense. While reviewing your application, we noticed that your account information matches a currently approved AdSense account associated with another.email@gmail.com. Because our policies do not permit multiple accounts, we're unable to accept your new application at this time.
>
> If you'd like to add my.email@gmail.com as a login to your approved account, you can do so by following these steps:
>
> Sign in to the AdSense account associated with another.email@gmail.com at www.google.com/adsense.
>
> ...
>
> Once you've invited my.email@gmail.com as a login to your account, please check that address for an email invite and follow the instructions to add this new login.

The problem is, the account another.email@gmail.com does not belong to me!

Why do I need to log into the account of another person, in order to get access to AdSense with **my** google account?

EDIT: I tried to use the login trouble-shooter. This is what I got; none of the options match the message that I actually get.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Login issues - AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1208328?hl=en&ref_topic=1190787)

> ## Problems signing in to your AdSense account?
>
> ### Regaining access to your account
>
> We'd like to get you back into your AdSense account as soon as possible, so please use our login
> troubleshooter to help us understand what's keeping you out of your
> account, and how we can best help you get back in. download
>
> #### Login troubleshooter
>
> [**This
> troubleshooter**](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2594929)
> is designed to help you troubleshoot common problems signing in to
> your AdSense account. At each step, we'll provide instructions or
> further questions to help narrow down the issue you're facing.
> Following the instructions exactly will help ensure the best results.
>
> #### Forgotten your password?
>
> Please visit [Google
> Accounts](https://www.google.com/accounts/ForgotPasswd) to have your
> password re-sent to you.

It's worth to say that sometimes, the trouble-shooters doesn't include all the possible troubles but some solutions for other could give an idea of things to try. If you didn't yet, click one by one the options there.

Another thing try, is to post a question as support request to the official [AdSense help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense)

Comment: I tried to use the login trouble-shooter, but none of the options match the message that I actually get. See the screenshot I just added to my question.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: I updated the answer to include there my reply to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question, generally Google does not allowed to use multiple adsense account from same person. May be someone, who's name and home address is just like yours, and got adsense account. And Google may be think, you applied for another account, that's why you got this notification.

What I suggest to do is, **Just slightly change your home address and apply again for Adsense with different email ID, don't worry you can change email ID, from setting option once you got approved**. Alternative way to contact Google AdSense team, and say I have no AdSense account, you can check my history, but it will take some days/months.

Answer (score 0):

This user does not have an AdSense account. Please check that the email address matches your AdSense account address. New accounts may take up to 24 hours to appear